# My BCM 4311 Wireless is not working. How can I fix this?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Hi I've spent hours trying all the suggestions listed on Forums on this problem all over the Internet and I still can't get my wireless working. It's very discouraging because it might force me to go back to Windows which I hate. Can someone help?

Perhaps I can give you some information to help identify what the issue is? b43 isn't coming up in my list of drivers...just Broadcom STA which doesn't work.

I think I've removed all the blacklisted stuff.

Comment: Did you find any suggestions to install drivers from source? Sometimes using the source fixes it.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I don't know if I know how to do that. I've installed the b43 several times from terminal:

Comment: 1 sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Comment: This page has been very useful but I still haven't got the b43 working:  http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here! This is the fix that I used to great success:

[Ubuntu 11.10 getting wireless BCM4311 working](http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/ubuntu-11-10-getting-wireless-bcm4311-working/)

The basics are this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

The article will give you more background on the issue.

Comment: I used a similar method to fix a friend's wireless before but could not remember the steps. I can confirm also that this works.

Comment: I finally got it to work! There were some blacklists on the bcm43xx in some hidden files that I think were responsible...but I'm not really sure. But it's finally working. Many thanks to you both for your help!

Comment: @Annie you can mark his answer as answering your question by clicking the tick next to it (gives him 15 rep as thanks, and 2 rep to you for accepting the answer :D) so that others will know this worked and that your answer is solved.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know: I spent hours trying to get wireless working on my parents' machine. Finally, I found this post, and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a community documentation on Broadcom BCM43xx PCI based wireless network card for Ubuntu 10.04 & onwards.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Installing_STA_drivers

There are methods for installing the drivers even without the Internet access.

If you don't have Ubuntu CD/USB, download four latest packages (dkms, patch, fakeroot, bcmwl) from

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/..

../pool/main/d/dkms

../pool/main/p/patch

../pool/main/f/fakeroot

../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl

Put the .deb files together in a folder, and install by typing this command in Terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Sorry about my bad English.